# Multisite - Getting Meta query to select from wp_2 tables

Tags: customization, loop

Quite new to Wordpress, so if you'll bear with me :-)

I was asked to create a feature which lists 4 featured products on the front page. Now the one requirement was that the feature was to only appear on one of the multisites. There are two, one for the US and one for the UK.

Currently my additional code is working n displaying featured products but its doing it for the US and I need it to rather look at the products from the UK site.

The US sites is siteid 1 (The primary site) and the UK is site id 2 in the multisite network setup.

The code which selects and displays the featured products is below.

```
<?php
$meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$meta_query[] = array(
  'key'   => '_featured',
  'value' => 'yes'
);

$args = array(
  'post_type'   =>  'product',
  'stock'       =>  1,
  'showposts'   =>  4,
  'orderby'     =>  'date',
  'order'       =>  'DESC',
  'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
);
?>
<section class="section padding shop home-shop">
  <h2>Featured Products</h2>
  <ul class="row articles">

<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();
    global $product;

    $product_image_size = array(200,200);
    $product_price = $product->get_price_html();
    $product_price = str_ireplace('Price', '', $product_price);
    $product_price = str_ireplace(':', '', $product_price);

    $product_title = get_the_title($loop->post->ID);
    $product_perma_link = get_permalink($loop->post->ID);
    $product_collection_link = get_option("shop_collection_url");

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ){
      $img_markup = get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, $product_image_size );
    }else{
        $img_markup = wc_placeholder_img($product_image_size);
    }

    ?><li class="columns medium-3 text-left row_0"><div><?php

    ?><div><?php echo $img_markup; ?></div><?php

    ?><div><?php echo $product_title; ?></div><?php
    ?><div><?php echo $product_price; ?></div><?php

    ?></div></li><?php

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
    <ul>
      <a href="<?php echo $product_collection_link; ?>">Shop the collection</a>
```

The code above is within its own php file (includes/php/sections/home-cherry-products.php) and that is included in the static home page file 'home-page.php' using 
    include('includes/php/sections/home-cherry-products.php');

Please note though that the file may be in the sections folder I am NOT using section to display the content.

Using 'switch_to_blog(2);' does seemingly switch the query to the second blog, but no products get returned.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to get products on US site from UK site.

You can use `switch_to_blog()` to direct your queries to your sub-site. This function uses `blog_id` as parameter.

So, in your case,

```
switch_to_blog(2);
//your code to fetch data
restore_current_blog(); //this restores query to current sub-site.
```

See documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/

Comment: Thats not working. If I use switch_to_blog(2); no products appear (I double checked I had products on the UK site set to featured) but as a test if I use switch_to_blog(1); then US products appear. Site code by the way is executed within page-home.php file so it is common to both sites. I put the above shown code into a php file then just included it with include('includes/php/sections/home-cherry-products.php');

Comment: I have output the data containing within the WP_Query variable 'loop' and I can see it is making calls against the table wp_2 but not sure why it is brining back anything. So you function call is probably correct in so far as it is pointing it to the correct tables.

Comment: There might be other `meta_query` which are not successful for UK site.